# Python Selenium Take a Screenshot Of An Whole Page Without Using Headless Mode

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, screenshot, undetected-chromedriver

I need to take a screenshot of an element which is very long and not fit on the screen, I can use headless mode to do this but site doesn't allow me to do even with user-agent and other stuff.

But I can access the site with undetectedChromeDriver, so there's a extension to do this stuff called 'HTML Elements Screenshot'.

That extension will allow you to select element and take the screenshot of an whole element for you.

I automated that process with pyautogui and cv2 but I want to do it without this libraries. Is there any Javascript code to do it ? I did my research but can't find any useful. Thanks in advance

The codes I tried:

```py
def save_screenshot(driver, path: str = 'screenshot.png') -> None:

        input('Let it go when u ready.')
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        original_size = driver.get_window_size()
        required_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
        required_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
        driver.set_window_size(required_width, required_height)
        driver.save_screenshot(path)  # has scrollbar
        #driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(path)  # avoids scrollbar
        driver.set_window_size(original_size['width'], original_size['height'])
```

```py
    def saveScreenshot(driver,path: str="screenshot.png"):

        input('Let it go when u ready.')
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        el = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"body")
        el.screenshot(path)
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python you can use [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/).

For javascript you can use [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)

[You can find the documentation here](https://pptr.dev/api/)

Comment: Can you give me sample about using that library on Python, I can't find any documentation about using it without headless mode.

Comment: Hope it helps for you : https://gist.github.com/enisgetmez/5c7129704ac7f9919593f83f91be1a8d For other examples you can check here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/119403/pyppeteer

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and work, it's work and what I looking for. I can't reach the site because of their anti-scrape detections but I'm gonna try the figure it out. Thankss !

Comment: I think I figure it out, first of all, I opened the page with undetected-chromdriver. After that save the page locally to my machine. I opened the local page with your example and it's worked like I want. <3